# Looking for a way to compare and merge two texts in python

Tags: python, version-control

I'm writing CMS in which any authorized user can change any content, but the changes should be approved by moderators. In this case two or more users can change the article simultaneously before moderators would approve any of changes. So we have something like branches in VCS and I'm looking for the way to compare and merge these branches as automatically as possible. How would you implement this on python? I would appreciate for any links on articles or libs.

Comment: Python is a good "glue language" - it's easy to interface with other programs and/or libs - so your best bet is probably to use some standard diff/merge tools,  either a full blown VCS or the libs they rely on.

Comment: You probably don't need to implement this, Mercurial is a VCS written in python, you can create hooks or use hglib which has a very good API.